# How get ranges of one column gruop by class column? In Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I'm practicing with Pandas and i want to get the ranges of a column from a  dataframe by the values of another column.

An example dataset:

```
     Points    Grade
1     7.5        C
2     9.3        A
3     NaN        A
4     1.3        F
5     8.7        B
6     9.5        A
7     7.9        C
8     4.5        F
9     8.0        B
10    6.8        D
11    5.0        D
```

I want group ranges of points for each grade so i can induce missing values.

For that goal i need gets something like this:

```
Grade      Points
  A      [9.5, 9.3]
  B      [8.7, 8.0]
  C      [7.5, 7.0]
  D      [6.8, 5.0]
  F      [1.3, 4.5]
```

I can get it with for and that kinds of stuffs but is it possible with pandas in some easy way?

I tried all groupby combinations i know and nothing. Some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter `df` with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df
    Points Grade
0      7.5     C
1      9.3     A
2      NaN     A
3      1.3     F
4      8.7     B
5      9.5     A
6      7.9     C
7      4.5     F
8      8.0     B
9      6.8     D
10     5.0     D
```

```
print df['Points'].notnull()
0      True
1      True
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
Name: Points, dtype: bool

print df.loc[df['Points'].notnull()]
    Points Grade
0      7.5     C
1      9.3     A
3      1.3     F
4      8.7     B
5      9.5     A
6      7.9     C
7      4.5     F
8      8.0     B
9      6.8     D
10     5.0     D

print df.loc[df['Points'].notnull()].groupby('Grade')['Points']
                                                   .apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
  Grade      Points
0     A  [9.3, 9.5]
1     B  [8.7, 8.0]
2     C  [7.5, 7.9]
3     D  [6.8, 5.0]
4     F  [1.3, 4.5]
```

Comment: oh! not exactly what i was looking for but works for me! ty!